# What is the harm in catching a StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Just curious. [In an answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/209101/24912) about catching StackOverflowErrors someone wrote: "Surely there are situations where a stack overflow might leave an application inconsistent just like a memory exhaustion". What's so special about StackOverflowErrors that they threaten to corrupt the application state more than, say, a NullPointerException thrown in case of a Bug? One thing I can think of is that a StackOverflowError can occur in places where normally never ever an exception (or other Throwable, for that matter) is thrown (e.g. a simple getter), so the program probably isn't prepared for this. Are there more diabolical problems?

Comment: I am thinking that a SOE will usually happen due to coding error rather than data error.  Other comments are saying "A stack overflow error is usually a bug" but isn't also usually a NPE?

Comment: @user2310289 There are many ways to fall on an NPE, so many you might want to skip some tests and rely on the try/catch system sometimes. But yes, catching a NPE should be rare too.

Comment: note that it is an Error! not an exception!

Comment: @PhilippSander I clarified that - I meant "exception" not in the sense of java.lang.Exception but as a generic term. I do not see a fundamental difference between java.lang.Error and java.lang.Exception though - except a strong hint that Errors are more serious and you usually cannot gracefully recover from that.

Answer (score 11):

A stack overflow error doesn't at all mean the memory is exhausted and doesn't make anything inconsistent per se.

But a stack overflow error is usually a bug. You should fix the bug instead of catching the exception. Don't use the exception system to hide bugs.

Even when you know there's a risk of a too deep stack (graph exploration for example), there are better ways to control that than letting the stack explode.

From [the Javadoc of the Error superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) :

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a
>   "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most
>   applications should not try to catch it.

Comment: Funny thing is...you actually can't catch this error. The VM crashes before you can do anything.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz - Actually, you can catch it ... if your JVM is properly implemented.  You just need to catch it far enough down that there is enough stack space to do what the handler needs to do.

Comment: Even if it really was an OutOfMemoryError - why would that make anything inconsistent - more than any other bug resulting in an exception would do? BTW: In a decent application you need to catch everything - including Errors - somewhere at the top level of the application to avoid presenting the enduser with a stacktrace and do maybe some error logging and bug reporting.

Comment: When you have an OutOfMemoryError you may try to log but any decent application *must* stop at that point.

Answer (score 0):

An error is a serious problem that should not be caught
therefore: also do not catch the super class (Throwable)
if a method throws an error you do not have to declare a throws-clause

The behavior of an application is often not predictable after an error 
- errors indicate an abnormal condition

So if an StackOverflowError has been thrown, the application reached the maximum of stack-places for now. You could recheck your application for starting e.g. the garbage collector sooner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite see what the garbage collector has to do with this. Anyway - my question was whether the SOE can have worse consequences than I indicated in the question.